# jQuery append inside appended element

Tags: jquery, append

I have the following jQuery code which works, but it made me ponder if it were possible to do an append action on what was being appended without the need of specifying what I wanted to append to. `append().append()` didn't do the trick, it just put the two elements next to each other and not a child of the first `append()` action.

## Works:

```
var container = $('#container'),
    child = 'child';

$('#container').append($('<div/>',{
    'id'    : 'child'
}));

$('#' + child).append($('<a/>', {
    'class' : 'close',
    'href'  : 'javascript:;',
    html    : 'close',
    click   : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + child).remove();
    }
}));
```

## Does Not Work:

```
var container = $('#container'),
    child = 'child';

$('#container').append($('<div/>',{
    'id'    : 'child'
})).append($('<a/>', {
    'class' : 'close',
    'href'  : 'javascript:;',
    html    : 'close',
    click   : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + child).remove();
    }
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8TwW/1/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to append the first `<div>` to the element with ID container, so that you have a reference to that new element, then use `.append()`:

```
$('<div/>',{
    'id'    : 'child'
}).appendTo('#container').append(
    $('<a/>', {
        'class' : 'close',
        'href'  : 'javascript:;',
        html    : 'close',
        click   : function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#' + child).remove();
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `append` doesn't return reference to the appended content. It is referring to the same object i.e. `container` after the first append, or no matter how many appends you would run. So as other suggested use `appendTo` or you can use the following that better demonstrate why you were failing:

```
var container = $('#container'),
child = 'child';

$('#container').append($('<div/>',{
    'id'    : 'child'
})).find('#' + child).append($('<a/>', {
    'class' : 'close',
    'href'  : 'javascript:;',
     html   : 'close',
     click  : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + child).remove();
     }
}));​
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y8TwW/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the appendto and then append
http://jsfiddle.net/Y8TwW/2/

```
var container = $('#container'),
    child = 'child';
$('<div/>', { 'id': child }
 ).appendTo(container
 ).append($('<a/>', {
    'class' : 'close',
    'href'  : 'javascript:;',
    html    : 'close',
    click   : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + child).remove();
    }
}));
```

Comment: Place the relevant code in the answer, not just a link to the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO more natural chaining looks like:

```
$("your_selector_to_search_root_element").append(
        $("<div />", {
            'class': someComplexCalculationForElementStateClass(conditionalInfo)
        }).append(
            $("<div class='fixed' />").append(
                "<div class='ico' />",
                "<a class='title' target='blank' href='#' >" + item.Title + "</a>",
            ),
            $("<div class='btn'>", ).append(
                "<a class='btn_link' href='#'>Remove</a>",
            )
        )
    );
```