# jQuery append <option> to appended <select>

Tags: jquery, append, html-select

I'm trying to append/prepend option tags to a appended select input in a form.
Simply my form is appended to the body like this:

```
c.append( $('<form>').attr({
  'method': 'POST',
  'action': ''
}).append( $('<select />').attr({
     'name': 'retour'
}) ));
```

Now I want to append Option tags to this form without having to create a `.append( $('<option>').attr() )` etc like 5 times.

I found questions like:

1. [jQuery append inside appended element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422501/jquery-append-inside-appended-element)
2. [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)
3. [Programmatically create select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601952/programmatically-create-select-list)

But none of them are working in my case.
Hopefully someone knows a answer, thank instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append accepts multiple elements separated by a comma

```
c.append( 
    $('<form>', {
         method : 'POST',
         action : ''
    }).append( 
        $('<select />', {
            name : 'retour'
        }).append(
            $('<option />', {text : 'option1'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option2'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option3'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option4'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option5'})
        )
    )
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7m7rX/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. But what if I want a array (like JSON) to by <option>?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I guess you would iterate over the array and create each option independently and append to the select etc.

Comment: I want to append <option> tags doing: `for(var i=0; i < elem.count; i++)`