# How to append to apendees?

Tags: jquery, html

It's been a while since my jQuery days and I was just struck by the realization that the following code:

```
$("#add").append("<div>1</div>").append("<div>2</div>")
```

didn't add a div with an **inside** div but rather two divs. I can do something like this

```
$("#add").append("<div>1<div>2</div></div>")
```

but it seems to me like hiding my ignorance, rather than producing a trustworthy solution. How can I append something with appended sub-elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery append inside appended element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422501/jquery-append-inside-appended-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) at this context,

```
$("<div>1</div>").appendTo("#add").append("<div>2</div>")
```

Since `.append()` will return the element over which it(`append`) was invoked.  So this `$(#add)` will be returned. Your code is very much similar to,

```
var elem = $("#add");
elem.append("<div>1</div>");
elem.append("<div>2</div>");
```

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps I'm not clear on what I'm trying to avoid. I want the second div to be appended to the first, not the outer called add. I want the divs to be nested inside each other.

Comment: @KonradViltersten My code will give you an output like `<div id="add"><div>1<div>2</div></div></div>` This is what you wanted. Right?

Comment: That's precisely what I want. I just can't understand how it's going to be achieved using your code. Sorry if I'm being dense. I've read the docs on *appendTo* but as I follow the example, I see that the *div-2* is going to be appended to *add-div* and not nested inside *div-1*. I want to nest without actually giving the div an ID.

Comment: Oh, wait. I just saw it. Just to verify - I could use *$().append().appendTo* as well, right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8os95zkb/ I think you misread the docs. The behavior is actually depends on the returning value from the function.

Comment: How can I easily verify what element is nested in which without drawing a bunch of borders?

Comment: @KonradViltersten `$().append().appendTo` No, That will append elements like `<div>2<div id="add"><div>1</div></div></div>`. You don't need to draw borders, you can inspect it to find that.

Comment: Sorry fo rnot being clear. You **are** correct and it **does** what you claim. I wonder, how I can verify for myself that it is so. Right now I do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8os95zkb/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108094/discussion-between-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy-and-konrad-viltersten).