# how do i reference an id with concatenated variable in jquery appendTo()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, concatenation

I am appending html code to a div using jquery. Part of that code references a div's id using a concatenated variable from a loop.

```
$(... +
    '<div class="recommendations filter" id="recCards-'+ i +'">' +
    '<div><h5>Recommended Cards</h5></div>' +
        '<ul></ul>' +
    '</div>' +
  ...
 ).appendTo('.someDiv');
```

I'm then trying to append code from another loop into the ul by referencing the ".recommendations" div's ID like so...

```
var recCardsList = $(div).attr('id', '.recCards-'"+i+"' ul');

$('<div>'+recCardName+'</div>').appendTo(recCardsList);
```

I've tried every combination of quotation marks that i can think of, but nothing grabs the div correctly to append the new content

Comment: You are putting css select as your id, `'.recCards-'"+i+"' ul'`. If you were trying to find the element it would be `$('#recCards-'+i+" ul")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code doesn't append the new created content to the `div`, because it has some errors:

```
var recCardsList = $(div).attr('id', '.recCards-'"+i+"' ul');
$('<div>'+recCardName+'</div>').appendTo(recCardsList);
```

By writing `.attr('id', '.recCards-'"+i+"' ul')` you are not getting the list from the `div` but, you are trying to update its `id`.

Actually if we pass two arguments to **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**, the first will be the targeted attribute and the second one is its new value.

So to get the div you should just use `$('#recCards-'+i+' ul')` in your loop it will gets the respective lists, so your code would look like:

```
var recCardsList = $('#recCards-'+i+' ul');
$('<div>'+recCardName+'</div>').appendTo(recCardsList);
```

Here using `$("#someId")` will get the element with the `id="someId"` from the page.

Comment: this is the solution. my misuse of .attr() is what made the div with the variable not show up. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var recCardsList = $(div).attr('id', '.recCards-'+i+' ul');
```

Comment: ID's don't have leading dots or spaces

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that variable i is still within the scope of the function the solution stated above

```
'recCards-'+i+' ul'
```

Would definitely work, as stated in the comment check either with console.log() or alert() what variable i is there is a chance due to what was given i is null.

If they are within the same function you can also look at this post to combine the 2 loops with appendTo() and append()

[jQuery append inside appended element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422501/jquery-append-inside-appended-element)

Answer (score 0):

You'll hardly get the list that way.
Try this:

```
var recCardsList = $('#recCards-' + i + ' ul');
```

Also it's not valid to append `<div>` to `<ul>`. It'd rather be `<li>`:

```
$('<li>'+recCardName+'</li>').appendTo(recCardsList);
```

Comment: yeah, that was a typo on my end, as i was rushing to post this question, while at work.

and i've tried that syntax, but it gives me errors

Comment: Could you please let me know which errors you've got?

Comment: actually nevermind. your answer is correct too. The fix to my problem was not using attr() and instead using $(), which you stated.

Comment: OK, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use mask and replace by i,

```
var strReccards = ".recCards-MYINDEX ul";
var recCardsList = $(div).attr('id', recCardIndex.replace("MYINDEX",i));
$('<div>'+recCardName+'</div>').appendTo(recCardsList);
```